# Long tail distributions

Tags: exponential-function, distribution-tails

I have just started to study sub-exponential distributions. I wonder how to prove this statement :
Let $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are independent random variables with distributions $F_1,\dots,F_n$ respectively. Suppose $F_1,\dots,F_n$ are all long tailed. Then, the distribution of $\max(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ is long tailed.

Comment: Hint: start from $$F_{\max_i X_i}(a) = \prod_i F_{X_i}(a).$$ Does the property of being long-tailed survive in the product on the right?